# Where can I find ASROCK E350M1 Integrated AMD Radeon HD 6310 graphics driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, hardware

I just built a desktop computer using an ASRock E350M1 board, powered by an AMD Fusion E-350 APU (AMD Radeon HD 6310 GPU Model). I installed Ubuntu 10.04. Did all the updates. Almost everything works great: I can see movies (DVD), surf, etc., but I cannot play games --screen frames are very, very slow. I have not installed any hardware drivers. When I search (in Ubuntu) for the hardware drivers, none are found.

I found here, http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware that the graphics card is officially supported: **PALM** | **Radeon HD 6250/6310**

If this is of any help, this is what I entered on the terminal:

> ```
> lspci -nn | grep VGA
> ```
>
> 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc Device
>   [1002:9802]
>
> ```
> ^C
> sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
> ```
>
> [sudo] password for pat:
>   Reading package
>   lists...
>   Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state
>   information...
>   Done debconf is already the newest version. libstdc++6
>   is already the newest version. libqtgui4 is already the newest
>   version. libqtgui4 set to manually installed. wget is already the
>   newest version. E: Couldn't find package dh-modaliases

I do not know what to do from here.

**Questions:**

- Where can I locate the drivers?
- How do I install the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to download and install AMDs proprietary driver from their website.

For 32 and 64-bit: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English

after downloading right click on the file and mark it as executable under properties. Now open a terminal and type in

```
sudo sh /home/your_username/Downloads/amd-driver-installer-12-2-x86.x86_64.run
```

the installer will guide you through the installation.
After the installation was succesful, type into the terminal

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

and finally

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: FYI, I got the drivers at AMDs driver page looking under 'Desktop Graphics' -> 'E-Series APU' -> 'E-350 APU' -> 'Linux x86_64'

Comment: Daniel, your instructions were concise, clear and exactly what I needed. Thanks also for telling me how you located the driver. please note that, for whatever reason, I was not able to use,"sudo sh /home/your_username/Downloads/amd-driver-installer-12-2-x86.x86_64.run" I received the following message, "Can't open /home/your_username/Downloads/amd-driver-installer-12-2-x86.x86_64.run 
pat@pat-desktop:~$"

Comment: oh sorry, you have to put the actual username of your ubuntu account where I put 'your_username' it was just a placeholder. Alternatively you can type sudo sh $HOME/Downloads/amd-driver-installer-12-2-x86.x86_64.run

Comment: Thanks again Daniel! Thanks also for showing me where to locate the driver. I should have figured out to put my username in place of 'your_username' but I am totally new to Linux...

Comment: My next step is to locate and install the Realtek drivers. Is the proper protocol to ask a new questions since it has nothing to do with graphics drivers?

Comment: please close this question first by accepting my answer and then open a new question with specific details for the issue you're having

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success with that exact board, which I have, with the 3.2 kernel in precise and the open-source radeon driver. (I am using the non-free firmware) I recommend installing the backport kernel and xserver-xorg-video-radeon.

I succeeded in installing Coreboot onto my ASROCK E350M1.