# Live usb does not boot on Asrock E350M1

Tags: installation, boot

I've just bought a new computer, with specs:

```
motherboard Asrock E350M1
processor AMD Dual Core E-350
graphic card ATI Radeon HD6310
```

and tried to install ubuntu 12.10 on it, from a live usb.

I'm never able to get to the install screen, I keep getting error messages like:

```
udev[110]: timeout killing /sbin/modprobe -bv pci:[characters]
udev[110]: timeout killing /sbin/modprobe -bv pci:[characters]
udev[110]: timeout killing /sbin/modprobe -bv pci:[characters]
...
```

Reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112905/where-can-i-find-asrock-e350m1-integrated-amd-radeon-hd-6310-graphics-driver), it's possible that I would need to install AMD drivers but how am I supposed to do that if I can't even boot? Should I install them on the live usb before trying to boot? Or is it another problem?

Edit: I've seen someone solved this problem by selecting "Os Select: Other" instead of "Os select: Windows" in the BIOS, but the problem is I don't have a bios, I have the Asrock UEFI... And this option is not present in Asrock UEFI.

Comment: I also tried with ubuntu 12.04 and same problem. Can someone point me in the good direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Asrock uefi (F11 when booting), go to "Advanced", then "Storage configuration", and switch the option "SATA IDE Combined Mode" to Disabled.

Don't forget to install a 64 bit version of ubuntu also.